# Giving extending classes a specific behaviour?

Tags: java

How can I have several extensions of a class `Fruit`, and based on what class/type the object ist, execute the same method on this fruit but with different function?

Example: I'm using a  `FruitManager` to add a new `Fruit fruit = new Apple();` to the fruitstore. If this fruit is an apple, I want of course to add this to the apples list. Elso to bananas list.
Now if I have 10 sorts of fruits, I do no want to create 10 functions like `addBanana()`, `addApple()` and so on.
And I too do not want to have cluttering if-else statements for getting the right fruit list.

Can I samehow get the fruitlist just based on the type of object I'm adding?

```
class Fruit;
class Apple extends Fruit;
class Banana extends Fruit;

class FruitStore {
    List<Fruit> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
    List<Fruit> bananas = nwe ArrayList<Banana>();
}

class FruitManager {
    FruitStore store;

    //called from somewhere with Fruit fruit = new Apple();
    addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        //how could things like this be done in one statement?
        store.<get list apples or bananas>.add(fruit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the need for storing them in separate lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making my kludge into an answer. Consider using a HashMap of `HashMap<Class<? extends Fruit>, List<Fruit>>`. Something like this:

```
class FruitStore {
   private Map<Class<? extends Fruit>, List<Fruit>> fruitMap = 
         new HashMap<Class<? extends Fruit>, List<Fruit>>();

   public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
      Class<? extends Fruit> fruitClass = fruit.getClass();
      List<Fruit> fruitList = fruitMap.get(fruitClass);
      if (fruitList == null) {
         fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
         fruitMap.put(fruitClass, fruitList);
      }
      fruitList.add(fruit);
   }

   public void displayStore() {
      for (List<Fruit> fruitList : fruitMap.values()) {
         System.out.println(fruitList);
      }
   }
}
```

I tested this with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FruitManager {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      FruitStore fruitStore = new FruitStore();
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         if (i % 3 == 0) {
            fruitStore.addFruit(new Banana());
         } else {
            fruitStore.addFruit(new Apple());
         }
      }

      fruitStore.displayStore();
   }
}

abstract class Fruit {
   public abstract String getName();

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return getName();
   }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {

   private static final String NAME = "Apple";

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return NAME;
   }

}


class Banana extends Fruit {

   private static final String NAME = "Banana";

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return NAME;
   }

}

class FruitStore {
   private Map<Class<? extends Fruit>, List<Fruit>> fruitMap = 
         new HashMap<Class<? extends Fruit>, List<Fruit>>();

   public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
      Class<? extends Fruit> fruitClass = fruit.getClass();
      List<Fruit> fruitList = fruitMap.get(fruitClass);
      if (fruitList == null) {
         fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
      }
      fruitList.add(fruit);
      fruitMap.put(fruitClass, fruitList);
   }

   public void displayStore() {
      for (List<Fruit> fruitList : fruitMap.values()) {
         System.out.println(fruitList);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully the other 5 people who upvoted your comment with also upvote this answer, since it's the best way to implement what OP wants.

Comment: The only change I'd recommend is to put the map.put method inside the if condition, thereby eliminating multiple redundant map.put calls - you only need to place the list in the map once, immediately after construction.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002: Yep that seems a better way to do things. Changes made, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While you can avoid the need for `addBanana(..)`, `addApple(..)`, and so forth, this isn't doable without several if-else statements, unless you want to lose quite a bit of program efficiency in using reflection.

```
public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
    if (fruit instanceof Apple) {
        store.apples.add(fruit);
    } else if (fruit instance of Banana) {
        store.bananas.add(fruit);
    } else if ... { }
}
```

If you *really* want to use the reflection method... here it is, but I don't recommend it.

```
public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
    try {
        Class<Fruit> clazz = fruit.getClass();
        String clazzName = clazz.getName();
        String listName = clazzName.toLowercase() + "s";
        Class<FruitStore> fsClazz = store.getClass();
        Field listField = fsClazz.getDeclaredField(listName);
        listField.setAccessible(true);
        List<Fruit> list = (List<Fruit>) listField.get(store);
        list.add(fruit);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // failed to add fruit
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note: The reflection method is untested, but the only issue I believe might occur is that `Field#get` returns a reference to a copy of its value rather than the reference to its value, resulting in `list.add(fruit)` adding to a different list than the one in the class.

Comment: I suppose you can kludge it using a `HashMap<Class, ArrayList<Fruit>>` 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not neccessarily a kludge. Sure, need to handle inheritance, but it's still a nice solution. You still have to prepare the `Map` (a lot of `add`s) but only once per runtime.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Fruit> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
```

Firstly, this is not valid in Java as a list of Fruits cannot point to a List of Apples because `List<Fruit>` can potentially contain anything that is Fruit, i.e an apple or a banana, whereas `ArrayList<Apple>` can contain only Apples.

Secondly, when you have an inheritance chain like this, you generally don't store them in separate lists. You would store them in a single list, a `List<Fruit>` and any operation that is performed on each element in this list will have polymorphic behavior and based on the actual type of `Fruit`, the behavior could be different as defined in the corresponding class.

So, you should rethink of your use case where you felt the need to store them separately.

Comment: That doesn't address the need to operate on the lists themselves.  For instance the implementation of something like getAllBananas().  Yes you can pull them out from the master list but it's incredibly inefficient.

Comment: Agree @FoolishSeth, except for the count operation, from a behavioral perspective, would you like to use instanceof operator or would you go with polymorphic behavior? If you use instanceof operator, how would you handle decorated fruits, for example a decorated Apple whose instanceof against Apple would fail?

Comment: I would go with a Map key'd on the class type.  Although to a certain extent it depends on how many different fruit types are anticipated.  Always a tricky design decision since you may not know, but it's not necessary to support infinite variety in every case.

Comment: That would still not address decorated objects, @FoolishSeth.

Comment: If you choose to break isntanceof through your implementation of decorators then you should be aware of the consequences of that decision.

Comment: @FoolishSeth, in a monolithic application with one/two developers, it is possible to make a conscious decision to not decorate because you are using instanceof in some parts of your code. But that is not feasible in an enterprise application with decent lifespan to carry such design decisions. I agree its subjective but I personally feel it is risky to design around instanceof or class of objects.